# Is it possible to create a minimum varchar length by utilizing a trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to have a minimum varchar length for a column of a table on inserts. I know that this isn't possible through varchar's native capability but would it be through utilizing a trigger? I was thinking it would look something like this:

create trigger ins_user before insert on accounts
for each row if (username > 5);

Does anybody have any advice? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What's the expected behavior if someone inserts a value that's too short? Do you want to fail the insert? Assign some default? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`CHECK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) constraint which are enforced starting from MySQL 8.0.16:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(
 ...
 username VARCHAR(100) CHECK (LENGTH(username)>5)
)
```